# Charaterisation of quaternion algebras

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, quaternions, division-algebras, division-rings

Let $k$ be a field, and $A$ an associative $k$-algebra with an identity element. Say that $A$ is *quadratic* if any subalgebra of $A$ generated by a single element has dimension at most two.

I am looking for a reference for the following (or any similar) result:

> Assume that ${\rm char}(k)\ne2$, and let $A$ be a quadratic division algebra over $k$ with $\dim_k(A)\ge3$. Then $A$ is a quaternion algebra.

(I expect this to be well known, but am not aware of any reference.)

Comment: A counterexample is the (commutative) algebra $A=k[x_i:1\le i\le n]/(x_ix_j:1\le i,j\le n)$ for $n\ge 2$. Every element has the form $t1_A+w$ with $t\in K$ and $w^2=0$, so generates a (unital) subalgebra of dimension $\le 2$.

Comment: @YCor: That is not a division algebra.

Comment: Ah sorry (I had reread carefully all your post to double check... except, apparently, at the right place!).

Comment: At least in finite dimension it follows from the fact that a division algebra has square dimension $n^2$ over its center, over which it has an $n$-dimensional commutative subalgebra.

Comment: The point being that a commutative subalgebra can have dimension at most two in this situation? Indeed, that is a good argument. However, I would like to  know if this or any similar result is available in the literature, for easy reference.

Comment: The commutative case being straightforward, so the question is whether a division algebra of dimension $d\ge 5$ has a subfield of dimension $\ge 3$, and if I'm correct the answer is yes when $d<\infty$ (maybe excluding char 2?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a great and well-studied question with a super nice answer!  See Theorem 3.5.1 of my book (http://quatalg.org).  You can also say something in characteristic 2 (see Theorem 6.2.8) if you refine "quadratic" = "degree 2" to "nonidentity standard involution".

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. It seems that your proof follows the same lines as the one by Palais for the real case (Palais: The classification of real division algebras, Amer. Math. Monthly 75 (1968), 366–368.)

Comment: Yes, the argument is not due to me, and I found echoes of it in many places!